# Largest possible volume of this box.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, volume, maxima-minima

> If 1200 $cm^2$ of material is available to make a box with a square base and an open top, and the largest possible volume of the box.

So apparently I got this one wrong but I don't know why. My professor's comments: "You need to isolate x in the initial equation, plug it into the volume equation and derive. Give this one another shot. I think you’ll get it."

$$x^2 + 4xh = 1200 = Perimter$$
$$4xh = 1200 - x^2$$
$$ h = \frac{1200 - x^2}{4x}$$

$$x^2 \cdot h = V$$

$$ x^2 \cdot \frac{1200 - x^2}{4x} = V$$
$$ \frac{x ( 1200 - x^2)}{4} = V$$

so far, so good?

so

$$V' = \frac{1}{4} ( \frac{d}{dx} ( x(1200 - x^2)))$$

$$= \frac{-2x^2 + (1200 - x^2)}{4} $$
$$ = \frac{-3x^2 + 1200}{4}$$

So the critical number I get is x = 20, h = 10, max volume = 4000. Right?

Comment: That's correct,

Comment: Looks good. For fullness, the first equation represents surface area of the box, since the units are square cm. Perimeter is a measure of only length. So the volume is 4000 sq cm

Comment: Looks good to me. I think your prof misread something or messed up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks good to me.
What did your professor say the correct answer was?
Can your professor explain their work?
How many other questions has
the professor messed up?

The only thing
I would have done differently,
and this is a personal preference
in this case,
is that I would have expanded
$x(1200-x^2)$
to
$1200x - x^3$
before differentiating,
so I would find 
the root of
$1200-3x^2=0$.
The result is the same, of course.